# What should i do with cloth if i want to rig my character

Tags: mesh, rigging

I have the eyes parented to the character and the cloth are separate objects, i want to start ringing an i'm not sure what should i do with the cloth, if i should join it parent it or what, the same question goes to the hair

I read that the body and the cloth should have a similar topology and i think they are pretty close. I know to that i can delete all the mesh under the cloth but i want to try to rig them together so i can learn more about this topic and how to avoid clipping when deforming them.
For the cloth i use solidify, and i will add details later on with normal maps

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to rig your cloth, the 2 first ones are quite similar. I'm not sure you will avoid any clipping though, you'll probably have to make some corrections:

**With Weight Transfer:** (2.79 and previous versions)

- Parent your body to your armature.
- Make sure that your cloth has no vertex groups or is not parented to your armature.
- Select your body, then your cloth, switch to Weight Paint mode.
- In the left menu (T) > Tools, click on the *Transfer Weights* button. On the bottom of the T menu you'll see some parameters. For *Sources Layers Selection* choose *By Name*, and for *Destination Layers Matching* choose *All Layers*.
- Come back in Object mode, select the cloth, then the armature, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> > *With Empty Groups*. The cloth should move with the bone and be parented the same way as the body.

**With Data Transfer modifier:**

- Parent your body to your armature.
- Make sure that your cloth has no vertex groups or is not parented to your armature.
- Give your cloth a *Data Transfer* modifier. For *Source Object*, choose your body. Click on the *Vertex Data* option, then on the *Vertex Group(s)* button. Then on the bottom of the modifier click on *Generate Data Layer* and apply the modifier.
- Come back in *Object* mode, select the cloth, then the armature, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> > *With Empty Groups*. The cloth should move with the bone and be parented the same way as the body.

**With the Mesh Deform modifier:**

As explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA) by Daniel Kreuter:

- Parent your body with its clothes to your armature (if the clothes are another object, choose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Armature Deform*).
- Delete all vertex groups from the clothes (select the vertices and on the right of the vertex groups list, down arrow menu and *Remove From All Groups*). Assign these vertices to a new vertex group.
- Create a mesh that is fully closed and that will encompass your whole clothes, i.e. that will be your « cage ».
- Select your cage, then shift select the armature and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *With Automatic Weight*. Give the necessary corrections in *Weight Paint* mode.
- Give your body a *Mesh Deform* modifier (put this modifier above any *Subsurf* modifier) and in the modifier choose the clothes vertex group. Choose the cage as the *Object* and click on *Bind*.

Comment: Is this the same method I should use in Blender 2.9?

Comment: What part of the answer are you referring to? I guess it depends on what you're trying to achieve, are you trying to use cloth simulation? in that case maybe use the link I gave you under your last question rather than the video I link here

Comment: A lot of youtube tutorials are saying to use your first suggestion 'with weight transfer' however my cloth deforms and I am unable to restore it to its original state

Comment: maybe take a look at this tuto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C7eftpocH0&feature=emb_logo

Comment: It sill deforms like in these pics https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202329/clothes-deform-when-i-parent-to-armature

Comment: Under 'armature' if I bind to bone envelopes it deforms less but still deforms :(

Comment: I figured it out. It was linked to rest position and pose position :)

Comment: oh ok great  ;)  i didn't take a look at the armature actually