# Blender 2.8 - Cloths Don't Follow Armature In Pose Mode or They Shift Positions

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

First off I'm very new to blender so this has been a huge learning experience for me.

I have generated a character using "MBLab" Add-On from blender. It has made an armature for me that I would like to have my cloths follow. The end goal is to be able to have a rigged character with cloths exported to my game engine of choice.

I have all the cloths modeled now I just need to make them follow the bones. However, I can't seem to get it to work, properly. Here is what I have done:

1. Selected the mesh, then selected the armature, and pressed Ctrl-P
2. I selected Armature Deform > With Empty Groups
3. I added the "Data Transfer" modifier, selected the character mesh as the "Vertex Data"
4. I go into pose mode and it doesn't move with the armature. I can rotate it just fine in object mode because of the parenting

I can get the clothing mesh to move with the armature if I select "Bone Envelops" in the Armature modifier. However, if do that the mesh is moved slightly and no longer aligns with the character.

How can I properly make my cloths move with the armature without shifting their positions? If there is no way to do that then how can I reset the clothing meshes' positions back to their original positions prior to selecting "Bone Envelops"?

[image: Selected Bone Envelops Here]

Without Bone Envelops:
[image]

With Bone Envelops:
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file (delete all the non important part of your mesh): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Okay I deleted everything except what was in my question: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QQl4kGpA/

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to correct with the method explained below, if it still doesn't work, try with the *Mesh Deform* method as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115320/what-should-i-do-with-cloth-if-i-want-to-rig-my-character).

- Deactivate the *Armature* modifier visibility (screen icon button) for both the arm and the straps, so that the armature doesn't move the one or the other:

[image]

- Then you can see that arm and straps are not aligned, and the object even go through each other, you need to correct this in *Object* mode and in *Edit* mode.

[image]
[image]

- Once you're good, in the strap's *Data Transfer* modifier, click on *Vertex Data*, on *Vertex Group(s)*, *Generate Data Layers* and *Apply*:

[image]

- Reactivate the armature visibility for both arm and straps, move the bones, it works, even though it will probably need some adjustments:

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you for this. I will try this out a little later today. 

Is there an easy way to re-align/snap the straps back to the body of the character without having to adjust the x,y,z coordinates manually?

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way, just enable Proportional Editing

Comment: Sounds good. Will do. I will have to watch a quick YouTube tutorial on Proportional Editing to get a little more grounding.

Comment: Moving this back to fix the character is terrible. There has to be a better way... This is going to take weeks if not close to a month at my speed to re-shape every single peice of clothing this character has. This is nightmare....

Comment: mmh, this should not be so complicated, but you could try another way, using a Mesh Deform modifier for your straps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA

Comment: Here I explain how to do it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115320/what-should-i-do-with-cloth-if-i-want-to-rig-my-character